# .Rproj file doesn't launch using Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server, renv, r-environment

I have an Renv package stored as tar.gz file.

I would like to unzip the folder and do the below steps

a) Click the .Rproj file

b) Use the "Install and Restart" option in Rstudio to build the package

However, the .Rproj file doesn't open. Instead, it keeps loading fprever and I get the below error.

> The Rstudio server isbtaking a long time to respond. It is possible
> that your Rsession jas become unresponsive. Do you want to terminate
> the currently running R session

I am new to R and Rstudio. Any advice on what should I do to open this .Rproj file?

Comment: You can use OS level commands/system calls to achieve it, being one solution. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu

Comment: we can try writing a bash script for that, try if that works. i'll try and let you kow, if i find somthing